# Eclipse plugin development: Best practice for login form?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing a Eclipse plugin. This plugin uses some REST services that require authentication. What is the best practice approach to implement a login form in an Eclipse plugin? Should I just use a pop up window or are there any more sophisticated methods available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard UI for logging in available in the Eclipse framework, so popping up some dialog is the way to go.